# Getting the updated div offset after applying a CSS class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement an effect where an image (it can be of varying sizes) zooms on hover with a border appears around it. The non-zoomed image is limited to a maximum size of 250px and the zoomed to 550px.

I do this by applying a class to the div on mouseenter and remove it on mouseleave. This works well enough, but the problem is that I want to detect if the div goes partly off-screen. To do this I need the offset of the transformed div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.image-container').on('mouseenter', function () {

        var y = $(this).offset().top,
            x = $(this).offset().left;

        console.log('old', x, y);

        $(this).addClass('image-hover');

        y = $(this).offset().top;
        x = $(this).offset().left;

        console.log('new', x, y);
    });

    $('.image-container').on('mouseleave', function () {

        $(this).removeClass('image-hover');
    });
});
```

If you look at the jsfiddle below, I get the *old* offsets after adding the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/6JZCW/14/

So, how to get the updated offsets? Is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to get offset of your $('.image-container'), but its padding never change, you change only the padding of '.image-block' so when you console.log do this

```
$('.image-block').offset().top;
$('.image-block').offset().top;
```